# MySQL - Grabbing blob file from server

Tags: mysql, blob

I want to grab the binary data of a file from an SQL database given file location.

According to http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1643/using-openrowset-to-read-large-files-into-sql-server/, for T-SQL, I can use OPENROWSET and BULK to grab a blob of binary data from the file location on local disk. I have tested this and it indeed works for Microsoft SQL Server.

However, is there an equivalent query for MySQL? BULK is specific to T-SQL and gives me a syntax error in MySQL.

Would it even be possible for me to grab the binary data of a file from a MySQL server if I know the filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tip explains how to insert a file into a blob with pure T-SQL (i.e., not using a helper language like e.g. PHP). The MySQL equivalent would be the [`LOAD_FILE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file). The example from the manual:

```
UPDATE t
SET blob_col=LOAD_FILE('/tmp/picture')
WHERE id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's large-object support doesn't work this way. You need to retrieve the contents of your BLOB using a `SELECT` query. Your data will arrive in your rowset.

You'll need to deal with [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) if your BLOBs are particularly large.